# Eligibility traces in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

According to Sutton's book - Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction, the update equation of Network weights is given by:

[image: theta = theta + alpha * delta * e]

where e<sub>t</sub> is the eligibility trace.
This is similar to a Gradient Descent update with an extra e<sub>t</sub>.
Can this eligibility trace be included in the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` in TensorFlow?

Comment: I'm assuming `theta`, `e`, and `delta` all have the same shape, in which case you just want elementwise multiplication of the gradient? Which could be accomplished via an identity op with a custom gradient placed before the value of a variable is used. If that sounds right I can put together an example.

Comment: That's right. `theta`, `e`, and `delta` have the shape `[Number_of_classes, 1]`

Comment: Ah, apparently there's already [tf.contrib.layers.scale_gradient](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L1837). Does that work for you?

Comment: Perfect. Could you post an example as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of using `tf.contrib.layers.scale_gradient` to do elementwise multiplication of gradients. In the forward pass it's just an identity op, and in the backward pass it multiplies gradients by its second argument.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  some_value = tf.constant([0.,0.,0.])
  scaled = tf.contrib.layers.scale_gradient(some_value, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
  (some_value_gradient,) = tf.gradients(tf.reduce_sum(scaled), some_value)
  with tf.Session():
    print(scaled.eval())
    print(some_value_gradient.eval())
```

Prints:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.1         0.2         0.30000001]
```